# using walker menu to add classes and attributes to elements

Tags: walker

I want to use wordpress walker menu to achieve exactly this menu structure:

```
<a href="#myid" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse">Item 1</a>
    <div class="collapse" id="myid">
      <a href="" class="list-group-item">Subitem 1</a>
      <a href="" class="list-group-item">Subitem 2</a>
      <a href="" class="list-group-item">Subitem 3</a>
    </div>
```

Here is my needs: 
1- every parent menu item should have an attribute of **data-toggle="collapse"** and a class of  **list-group-item** 
2- all the anchor elements should have a class of **list-group-item** 
3- all the children of parent menu item should be wrapped inside a div with the class of **collapse** and the id of this div should be equal to the href attribute of parent menu item. for example: parent menu has **"a href='#myid' "** so the container div for children of this parent menu should have **an id of myid**

I'm not good at working with menu walker class so could you please help me with that?

I tried some more and now I have something but not complete. could you help me with that? thank you.

```
<?php
class wp_bt_navwalker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

  public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $indent = str_repeat( "\t", $depth );
    $output .= "\n$indent<ul id=\"364\" class=\"collapse\">\n";
  }


  public function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
    $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';
    $atts = array();
      $atts['title']  = ! empty( $item->title ) ? $item->title  : '';
      $atts['target'] = ! empty( $item->target )  ? $item->target : '';
      $atts['rel']    = ! empty( $item->xfn )   ? $item->xfn  : '';

      // If item has_children add atts to a.
      if ( $args->has_children && $depth === 0 ) {
        $atts['href']       = '#'.$item->ID;
        $atts['data-toggle']  = 'collapse';
        $atts['class']      = 'list-group-item';
      } else {
        $atts['href'] = ! empty( $item->url ) ? $item->url : '';
      }
```

Comment: any suggestion?